# How can I get previous state with redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an app in React and I ve split my state using Redux in 2 reducers. In one of my components I fetch some data from a server when it mounts and I also have a delete button.

The action I m using to fetch data when the component mounts, I want to use it in **componentDidUpdate** as well so once I m deleting and item from the list, I will update the list. I logged the previous state from **componentDidUpdate** and I saw that is still using the state from the component.

Is it any way that I can access the previous state from **Redux** so I can compare with the current state in **componentDidUpdate** so I don t enter in an infinite loop?

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` gives you access to the previous state, `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)` the current props would just be `this.props`. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Prev props give me an object with history, location and other stuff, but I m interested in the previous state from Redux so I can compare with the old state and if it s the same, fetchOrders function won t run again and update the state and enter in an infinite loop. Also prevState in componentDidUpdate gives me the state from within the component, but I don t have the list in there anymore, I manage it via  Redux.

Comment: the props to your component are from the redux state assuming you connected it. Can you post some code and or a jsfiddle replicating your issue. Not going to be able to help without that

Comment: prevState is the local components state. prevProps would be whatever props this component receives.

Comment: Oh wait I ve checked it again and yes, that array is in there on the prev props. I guess I ll do the check via prevProps. Thank you for your help. I thought that on props you don t get any state related info, but I forgot that Redux will pass the slices of the state via props.

Comment: yep! and you use the transition there to make a change. Make sure its a transition. like `if (!prevProps.somethingImportant && this.props.somethingImportant)`

Comment: Yes, in my case it s quite simple. I m checking after each delete/update if lengths of the arrays are the same or not and only if they re not fetch function can run. One thing that I can t understand is, for example If I dont  have any list item in the array I want to replace the sub component that displays the lists with a paragraph like: please add some items. It works only if I refresh the page, but if I delete all items I want to to also be displayed. I thought that deleting would trigger the render and run the code that replaces the sub component with that paragraph but it doesn t

Comment: Oh I fixed it. It shows a paragraph too, it was some typo in there. All works great now :)

Comment: Nice! glad it all worked out! :) I wrote up what we talked about as an answer if you'd like to mark it as the answer so we can close this open question out! :) +1 from me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `componentDidUpdate` to achieve this

Redux passes a fragment of the state to your components as props (i.e whatever you define in `mapStateToProps`)

You can use the transition of the redux state value in did update like so

```
componentDidUpdate(props) {
  if (this.props.someImportantItem && !props.someImportantItem || this.props.someImportantItem !== props.someImportantItem) {
    // code here to make a request
  }
}
```