# How to call method in child component only once after parent state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one parent and one child. The parent retrieves data (data is named blurts) using a fetch request, and sends the data via props to the child component. The child component is a lazy-loader component that only displays 6 records at a time as the user scrolls.

The lazy component creates its own state (array) based on the number of parent component records, which determines whether a record should be visible. All isVisible properties are set to false initially.

componentDidMount() in lazy component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    var isVisibleArray = this.props.blurts.map(item => {
        return false;
    });
    this.setState({ isVisible: isVisibleArray });
    this.PushBlurtArray();
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.LazyLoader);
}
```

Then, PushBlurtArray() method is called in order to set the first 6 records to visible. This method is also called each time the user scrolls to the sixth record. Internal state in the lazy-loader keeps track of this and sets 6 more to visible as needed.

PushBlurtArray() in lazy component:

```
PushBlurtArray() {
    // Initial values that keep track of lazy state.
    var renderCount = this.state.lazyState.skipCount,
        numRendered = this.state.numberRendered,
        isVisibleUpdate = this.state.isVisible;

        // Logic to get the next 6 (or less) blurts in the array and set isVisible to true
        // each time this method is called by the lazyloader method.
        for(let i=numRendered; i<renderCount; i++) {
            if (this.props.blurts[i]) {
                isVisibleUpdate[i] = true;
                numRendered++;
            }
        }

        // Update state accordingly so the loop iterates over the proper numerical
        // sequence keeping the blurts in order of consecutive sixes.
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            lazyState: {
                lzyLoading: true,
                skipCount: prevState.lazyState.skipCount + prevState.lazyState.skipInc,
                skipInc: 6,
                skipDb: prevState.lazyState.skipDb
            },
            isVisible: isVisibleUpdate,
            numberRendered: numRendered
        }));
}
```

This works properly up to a point. The restraint I’m having trouble with is that the parent component only pulls an initial count of 42 records. Then, once the lazy loader has iterated through all 42, I call a method in the parent that mounts another 42 records to its state, which in turn re-renders the lazy-loader. In theory this should go on indefinitely without issue.

The problem I’m having is that PushBlurtArray() needs to get called once the 42 additional records has been added to the parent state. If I call PushBlurtArray() in the render() method, or in componentDidUpdate(), it ends up calling PushBlurtArray() repetitively which pretty much screws up the entire ordeal.

I need a way to call PushBlurtArray() just once, after the 42 records has been added to state in the parent component.

Comment: [in your componentDidUpdate you can do a conditional check for a transition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56499617/2733506). This works for both `state` as well as `props`. for example `if (prevProps.someValue !== this.props.someValue) { //update here }`. You can do this check with the length of the array of elements for instance. `if (prevProps.lazyloadedElems.length !== this.props.lazyloadedElems.length)` for instance

Comment: @JohnRuddell Thanks! This was the only logical solution for me as well. I tried shallow comparison which does nothing. Next, I tried `if (prevProps.blurts.length !== this.props.blurts.length) { this.PushBlurtArray(); }` which allows everything to render properly, but it doesn't call PushBlurtArray. In fact the condition is never even met, I tested with a `console.log()` which means for some reason the props aren't updating after parent state change... I guess. Thanks for helping out this issue is killing me.

Comment: If you can replicate the issue on a codesandbox, i'd be happy to fix it for you. Hard though with the current context

Comment: @JohnRuddell No need your solution is correct. I just realized that I had an issue where my `fetch` to mount the additional 42 records was returning an empty array. So there was no change to parent state array length. If you'd like to post an answer regarding proper usage of `componentDidUpdate` in this context I'd be glad to accept as the answer. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the transition of your data inside `componentDidUpdate`. In this instance you want to check for the length of your array to determine when it changes.

```
componentDidUpdate(props) {
  if (
    (this.props.blurts.length > 0 && !props.blurts.length) ||
    this.props.blurts.length !== props.blurts.length
  ) {
    this.PushBlurtArray();
  }
}
```